# Delete relative row from three different tables in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables.

```
corp_id (PK) | corp_name
----------------------------------------
1                   | freshfruit 
2                   | realsteel
3                   | firmwall

corp_id (FK)| empl_id (PK) | empl_name
--------------------------------------------------------
1                   | 1                   | andy
1                   | 2                   | maria
2                   | 3                   | john
2                   | 4                   | neil
3                   | 5                   | stephan
3                   | 6                   | darwing

empl_id (FK)| client_id (PK)| client_name
---------------------------------------------------------------
1                   | 1                    | moris
1                   | 2                    | bean
1                   | 3                    | bay
3                   | 4                    | phill
4                   | 5                    | hank
5                   | 6                    | suzy
```

If I delete row in table 1, how do I get to delete rows in table 2 which are the related FK to the deleted row in table 1, and also I get to delete rows in table 3 which are the related FK to the deleted rows in table 2? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `onDelete('cascade')` in your foreign key reference.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the currently exisitng foreign key constraints and then add them again with `ON DELETE CASCADE`:

```
ALTER TABLE table2 DROP FOREIGN KEY corp_id

ALTER TABLE table2
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_2
FOREIGN KEY (corp_id) REFERENCES table1 ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Make similar changes for the third table.

Answer (score 0):

while creating table employee and client table, add following line:

```
corp_id REFERENCES corp_table (corp_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

similarly for 3rd table, add line after reference key.

Comment: What if I have created the tables? How do I alter them to get that constraint?